# Cart throb not emptying cart after successful checkout

Tags: cartthrob

I am running EE 2.5.5 the CT 2.2.9 (latest version).

I have been alerted by my client that when visitors are checking out, the basket is not emptying. This causes problems if a user then tries to checkout again, as the previous product can be sold out and still tries to checkout with it.

I can't see any setting for this in the cp. Anyone seeing or have seen a similar issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [**Clear Cart**](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/clear_cart/index.html) tag to your checkout workflow to force the cart to empty.

```
{exp:cartthrob:clear_cart return="cart/home"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something like this at one point - if the administrator "successful order" email does not get sent, the basket does not get cleared properly - there's sort of an order of operations behind the scenes in CartThrob, each triggering the next action. Are your administrator email notifications being sent and received when a customer goes through the checkout?  Once I got the admin emails working, the checkout clearing was fixed at the same time in my case.

Comment: Notification emails are sent out fine. Inventory is also increased, and orders are completed correctly. The only problem is that they aren't removed from the basket. This is a real strange one...

Comment: Was there any solution to this issue, I'm having a similar issue with no email notifications being triggered (and the cart isn't clearing) after a successful purchase.